# SQL: Counting the Number of Distinct Rows Per Year

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table ("my_table"):

```
    student_id scholarship faculty year_parking_ticket_received year_parking_ticket_paid
1            1           0       1                         2015                     2022
2            1           0       1                         2016                     2017
3            1           0       1                         2017                     2022
4            1           0       1                         2018                     2019
5            1           0       1                         2019                     2018
6            1           0       1                         2020                     2023
7            1           0       1                         2021                     2022
8            1           0       1                         2022                     2023
9            1           0       1                         2023                     2015
10           2           0       1                         2015                     2016
11           2           0       1                         2016                     2023
12           2           0       1                         2017                     2021
13           2           0       1                         2018                     2015
14           2           0       1                         2019                     2023
```

**I want to find out:** In each year , for each combination of faculty and scholarship : how many parking tickets were paid?

The final result should have the following format (note: I just made these numbers up):

```
  scholarship faculty year_parking_ticket_paid number_of_tickets_paid
1         1    1                     2010                     15
2         1    1                     2011                     19
3         1    1                     2012                    22
```

This would read as:

- In 2010, 15  students in the art faculty with scholarships  paid their parking tickets
- In 2011, 19 students in the art faculty with scholarships paid their parking tickets
- etc.

I tried to solve the question this way:

```
select sum_schol, sum_fac, number_of_tickets, count(*)
from
(select student_id, year_parking_ticket_paid, sum(scholarship) as sum_schol, sum(faculty) as sum_fac, count(*) as number_of_tickets
from my_table
group by student_id, number_of_tickets) as B
group by student_id, year_parking_ticket_paid, sum_schol, sum_fac
```

But I am getting this error: `GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregates!`

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

Notes:

- Let's assume that the student can not change their scholarship and faculty in same year , e.g. if student_id = 7 paid 3 tickets in year_paid = 2010 ...  it is impossible for student_id = 7 to have different values of scholarship and faculty in 2010
- For all intent and purposes, it seems that the year_parking_ticket_received is not of direct importance in this question: we are only interested in knowing the scholarship and faculty of a student in the year that the student **pays** the ticket - not the year that the student **receives** the ticket
- Naturally, the same student's properties in one year can contribute to the counts for (scholarship = 1 and faculty = 1) ... and in another year, the same student's properties can contribute to the counts for (scholarship = 1 and faculty = 0)
- Scholarship can only equal to (0,1) and Faculty can only equal to (0,1)

Comment: scholarship should not be summed - that is a true/false field. It should be one of the groups. Same for faculty. (`group by year_parking_ticket_paid, faculty, scholarship`). I do not think you need a nested query (`select * from (select * from ...))`)

Answer (score 1):

As to your error, it is self-explanatory. You have the things you are counting and summing in the GROUP BY clause, which is invalid.

Here, you are interested in a count, and what you are counting is tickets paid. You are grouping by `year_ticket_paid`, and also by `faculty` (true/false) and `scholarship` (true/false). So, its straightforward: three groups, and one count() for each of the groups.

```
select 
    faculty,
    scholarship,
    year_parking_ticket_paid,
    count(number_of_tickets_paid) as CountOfTicketsPaid
from 
    my_table
group by 
    faculty, scholarship, year_parking_ticket_paid;
```

Note that something to point out is that not all tickets are paid - so counts would probably be generally lower (and possibly misleading) if tickets mostly go unpaid.

Also, IF you wanted only faculty with scholarships, add a WHERE clause *before* the GROUP BY clause, and you will not get results for non-faculty or faculty without scholarships):

```
where
    faculty = 1
    and scholarship = 1
group by 
    faculty, scholarship, year_parking_ticket_paid;
```